# how to style pagination using Core UI smart table

Tags: css, angular, pagination, core-ui

I am trying to change the color of pagination buttons using Core UI smart table in Angular. Here is a photo of my code:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Open the tools navigator (F12). Select the active page. Then you can see what class is applied.

You'll see some like:
.page-link.active, .active > .page-link {
z-index: 3;
color: var(--cui-pagination-active-color);
background-color: var(--cui-pagination-active-bg);
border-color: var(--cui-pagination-active-border-color);
}

To override you can create a more specific css class like

```
.custom-paginator .page-link.active, .active > .page-link {
  z-index: 3;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

or, better

```
.custom .pagination
{
  --cui-pagination-active-bg: red;
  --cui-pagination-active-border-color: red;
}
```

This .css should be global, so add to your styles.css

Then only add the class to the paginator

```
<c-smart-pagination class="custom" ...></c-smart-pagination>
```

NOTE: Please, not post code as images, it's hard to read, no accessible and furthermore, if the image is loosed, the question becomes unintelligible